# Setting up a scheduled task on windows with a script

Tags: windows, scripting, scheduled-task

I want to dynamically setup scheduled tasks in windows.

So far I have a bat script that deploys some software in various places. The next step would be to start/stop those programs at certain intervals through scheduled tasks. Hence they have to run a certain script every hour or so...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schtasks.exe utility can do this.  [Here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736357%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the usage.

Comment: You can find example usage in Evan's response to this question of mine: http://serverfault.com/questions/58446/editing-scheduled-tasks-ntbackup-job-files

Answer (score 1):

The "at" command in windows can be used in command line, it schedules the task you want.